# Android DownloadManager class: getUriForDownloadedFile return wrong path

Tags: android

i download a .apk file with DownloadManager library, and i have a BroadcastReceiver for download service. here is my code in onRecieve():

```
  long id = intent.getExtras().getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID);
  DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.setDataAndType(dm.getUriForDownloadedFile(id), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

the problem here is when i call UriForDownloadedFile(id) somtimes return file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/example.apk
and on another device return
content://downloads/all_downloads/183

and i cant install apk with (content://downloads/all_downloads/183) path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know where the `DownloadManager` downloaded the file, as you were the one who told it where to download it. So, get rid of `getUriForDownloadedFile(id)` on Android 6.0 and older devices, and use `Uri.fromFile()` for the `File` that you told `DownloadManager` to download the file to.

Note that on Android 7.0+, you have to use a `content` `Uri` for this, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 24 or higher. Fortunately, the installer knows how to handle `content` schemes on Android 7.0 and higher.

Comment: **A Note! The `DownloadManager` does not always download into the path that I have determined for it!** When? When the file already exists in the path. Then the `DownloadManager` download it into an alternative path.

Answer (score 3):

```
registerReceiver(
      new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              final long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
              if (downloadId == 0) return;

              final Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(
                  new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));

              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                  final String downloadedTo = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                  Log.d(TAG, "The file has been downloaded to: " + downloadedTo);

                  context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        .setDataAndType(Uri.parse(downloadedTo),
                              "application/pdf"));
              }
          }
      },
      new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```