# File downloading in an android app (with kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I have been working on how to download a file (audio,image,...) from the internet using `DownloadManager` and `BroadcastReceiver`. Though I have made some progress and got some results, it is still not fully working and I can't find a good tutorial for what I need to do.

I got to the point where I get a signal in the *onReceive()* method of the `BroadcastReceiver` telling me that the download is complete. But I don't know how to make use of the result, I mean access the actual file for example to play an audio or display an image (or do whatever with the file).

Here is the relevant code for the problem:

```
    var brdCstRcvr = object:BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            val id = p1?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)

            if (id == downloadID) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Download Completed !!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val mgr = applicationContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                val uri:Uri = mgr.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadID)

                println("URI="+uri.toString())
                println("URI-Path="+uri.path)
                // What to do here to make use of the downloaded file?
            }
        }
    }
```

When running the app, the code above executes: I can see the message *"Download Completed !!!"*.
I can also see the results of the 2 *println* lines in the console.
What I need is to know how to use what I have to get access to the actual file.
I have tried a few things that I found reading the net, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm confused -- are you saying that you're getting the URI for the downloaded file to print out? If that's the case, then that's all you need to access that file

Comment: OK. Wonderful then. How to I access a file using its URI?
I usually access it with a path. And on Android I am not sot sure.
For example what it the code that I should add to get the size of the file? Or to display it if it is a text file?

Comment: `I can see the message "Download Completed !` Again you are talking about your own message...

Comment: @blackapps. Well, this is code that I found on the net (in some tutorial). Sorry if the message is not placed appropriately and thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're successfully downloading the file, and getting the URI. Depending on the location of that file (like if it's on external storage), you may have to deal with file access permission APIs. But in short, all you need is:

```
var file = File(uri.getPath())
```

Comment: No it is not on external storage, because I did not use .setDestinationUri(someThing) on the DownloadManager.

Comment: Then you can use the code in my answer

Comment: I just made an experiment based on your answer, using this code:
var file = File(uri.getPath()); println("file-size="+file.length())

I get the answer file-size=0. But the real file is about 600KB.
So something is not working.

Comment: You should check your logcat -- you're probably getting a permissions error, which means you would need to deal with that. What's the actual value for uri.getPath()?

Comment: and what do you get if you check file.exists()?

Comment: The result of executing:

println("URI-Path="+uri.path);

is:

URI-Path=/all_downloads/335

Comment: That's the downloads folder on external storage, so you'll definitely have to deal with permissions. Also, you never answered --  what do you get when checking `file.exists()`?

Comment: Indeed, when running the code: if (file.exists()) println("YES") else println("NO")

I get the answer NO.

Comment: In that case, you should be using the file URI that you told the DownloadMaganer to use in the first place, instead of trying to use `getUriForDownloadedFile()`. Here's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617458/how-do-i-get-the-uri-of-a-file-that-i-just-downloaded-using-the-downloadmanager

Comment: OK, I will look into that. Is it normal that it tries to access the downloads folder on external storage when I did not use .setDestinationUri(someThing) on the DownloadManager?

Comment: I did not tell the DownloadMaganer to use any URI, because I do not want to use the external storage.

Comment: and it uses the downloads folder by default, which is on external storage. So, you should definitely use setDestinationUri(), which will tell you exactly where to find it later

Comment: The DownloadManager documentation says:
"By default, downloads are saved to a generated filename in the shared download cache and may be deleted by the system at any time to reclaim space.
(Otherwise it should be EXTERNAL_STORAGE)"
And you are saying that:
"the downloads folder by default is on external storage."
Am I correct? If YES there seem to be a contradiction.
And if there is a folder by default, this is because I have the option not to use .setDestinationUri(someThing).
I am no expert with DownloadManager, but please check. And again I do not want to use the external storage.

Comment: `And again I do not want to use the external storage` Can be. You said that before. Im pretty shure DownloadManager saves to external storage too.

Comment: `var file = File(uri.getPath())` No. That makes no sense. You never tried that yourself and are waisting Michel's valuable time.

Comment: If course I tried it. If it was a valid file uri, it would have worked. But on some devices, instead of a file you around, and points to a file provider URI, which seems to be the case for him. And that's why it didn't work. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324376/android-downloadmanager-class-geturifordownloadedfile-return-wrong-path

Answer (score 0):

You access a file using its uri by opening an inputstream for the uri and then read the content from the stream.

```
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri):
```

And uri.getPath() does not give a file system path

Comment: I tried (in various ways) to translate this code in kotlin but could not make it work: "InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)"

Comment: Try more an read more stackoverflow pages tagged `android` and `kotlin`.

Comment: OP asked for kotlin, and you reply with java and tell to search more?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this steps in Kotlin you can Download files from any WebView

1- Add these to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

2- Add these settings to your webview

```
val webViewSettings = binding.your@id@webview(InsideXML).settings 

        webViewSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true //Needed 

        webViewSettings.domStorageEnabled = true //Needed 

        webViewSettings.allowFileAccess = true //Needed 

        webViewSettings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true //Needed 

----Yo can have more here but this are needed -----
```

3-Handle the downloads

```
   //handle downloading 

        binding.wvBase.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, _ -> 

            val request = DownloadManager.Request( 

                Uri.parse(url) 

            ) 

            request.setMimeType(mimeType) 

            val cookies: String = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url) 

            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies) 

            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent) 

           // request.setDescription("Downloading File...") 

            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)) 

            // request.allowScanningByMediaScanner() 

        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED) 

            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( 

                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName( 

                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType 

                ) 

            ) 

            val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager 

            dm.enqueue(request) 

            alertdialog() 

        }
```

In my case I have a custom alert Dialog to control if user says no, yes.